# I can't pull up my localhost server after putting in npm start

Tags: reactjs, npm

I had it pulled up earlier. I'm running npm start but it doesnt pull up for me.

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/reidwilliamson/.npm/_logs/2022-01-08T15_15_13_431Z-debug.log
```

Comment: are you executing `npm start` in the correct directory, ie the directory where your `package.json` is located? Is there a `start` script defined in your `package.json`? At least one of these questions is to be answered with NO. Please show the content of your `package.json`

Comment: Please consider providing a bit more context. But I agree with @derpirscher that you simply are in a wrong directory with missing package.json file

Comment: Please post the output of `npm run` like suggested in the message

Comment: So I deleted the other package.json file that didn't have the start property but still having the same issue when I npm start.

Comment: It says npm ERR! Missing script: "start"

Comment: Again: show the `package.json` file, which is located *in the same directory*  where you are trying to execute `npm start`. Such basic things typically aren't broken in npm, because if they were, thousands of developers would notice. So if `npm` complains about a missing start script, chances are high, you didn't add the `start` script correctly ...

Comment: So the issue was I hadn't cd'd into the correct file before running npm start.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you haven't set a `start` property in the `scripts` property of your `package.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I have 2 package.json files.. one doesn't have the "start" in it. I had created a "server-api" folder that holds this. I'm doing a project tutorial on youtube and think i got lost when creating this server-api folder.